# Cannot understand the proof

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I was studying the proof for absolute convergence test. I could not understand the following expression while reading it. Could you, please, explain what this means?
$$
x_+ = \max\{x, 0\},\qquad
x_− = \max\{−x, 0\}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that$$x_+=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x>0\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}\text{ and that }x_-=\begin{cases}-x&\text{ if }-x>0\ (\iff x<0)\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$